# Loading User LaunchAgent Successfully

Tags: macos, ssh, launchd, plist

I have created a plist file to replace an *xinetd* process that I used successfully in Windows (Cygwin) and Linux to stream an *imapd* connection from a remote server via `ssh` on a port on the localhost.

The `plutil` command says my configuration is OK. `launchctl load path-to-plist` runs without errors.

When I run `launchctl list` the agent does not display.  When I try to connect to the port on the localhost, I get connection refused.

Here is my plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
            <string>com.my.ssh_tunnel</string>
        <key>Program</key>
            <string>/usr/bin/ssh</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
            <array>
                    <string>-F /Users/userx/.ssh/config</string>
                    <string>dname /usr/sbin/imapd</string>
            </array>
        <key>Sockets</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Listeners</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>SockServiceName</key>
                        <string>dname-imapd</string>
                    <key>SockType</key>
                        <string>stream</string>
                    <key>SockProtocol</key>
                        <string>TCP</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
            <dict>
                <key>Disabled</key>
                <false/>
                <key>Wait</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
            <dict>
                <key>SSH_AUTH_SOCK</key>
                    <string>/Users/userx/.ssh-agent.sock</string>
            </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I have added a line to /etc/services for *dname-imapd* and an unassigned port (49022).  Ultimately I will be using this in conjunction with ssh-agent (to make this work 'passwordless') and Thunderbird to retrieve mail from a very locked down system.

There are essentially two questions here.  One, how do I know my agent is being loaded (and how do I confirm that)?  Two, is my plist actually correct?

Here's my original *xinetd* config:

```
service imapssh
{
        disable         = no
        type            = UNLISTED
        port            = 2208
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        wait            = no
        server          = /usr/bin/ssh
        server_args     = dname /usr/sbin/imapd
        user            = userx
}
```

Thanks for any help.  This is driving me a little crazy.

This is on an El Capitan Macbook Pro.

Also, I've tried a straight ssh tunnel but that doesn't really work (before anyone suggests it).  Unless someone knows how to make it work like *inetd* and spawn every time the mail client connects to the port.

Comment: I think your array `ProgramArguments` should be splitted in 4 `<string>…</string>`, one for each `argv[i]`, as `<string>-F</string>…`.

Comment: The existing, working plists don't seem to have an issue with more than one string inside a string tag.

Answer (score 1):

OK, addressing your second question first (*is my plist actually correct?*), `plutil` (in its default invocation) "lints" (checks) `plist` files for correctness:

```
plutil ~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.brew.update.plist
```

Equivalent to:

```
plutil -lint ~/Library/LaunchAgents/local.brew.update.plist
```

Turning to your first question (*how do I know my agent is being loaded (and how do I confirm that)?*), here's a few things to help check that.

First, I'd recommend adding logging to aid debugging. I log to `~/Library/Logs`, so add something like this to my `plist`:

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/Users/userx/Library/Logs/local.brew.update.stdout</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/Users/userx/Library/Logs/local.brew.update.stderr</string>
```

Try re-loading your `plist` and then check your logs:

```
less ~/Library/Logs/local.brew.update.stdout
less ~/Library/Logs/local.brew.update.stderr
```

A few additional observations:

My understanding of your `inetdCompatibility` is that the agent should start when it's loaded. However, you say that `launchctl list` doesn't show the agent. Does that change if you try `launchctl start com.my.ssh_tunnel` after loading the `plist`? Do the logs show anything new?

I don't entirely understand the relationship between `Program` and `ProgramArguments` - could just be me, but I find `man launchd.plist`'s explanation of `ProgramArguments` hard-going. I'd be inclined to try adding `/usr/bin/ssh` as a first `string` in `ProgramArguments`, and removing the entry for `Program`. (Then re-load and check the logs. Re-start and check the logs if needed).

Finally, I'm pretty certain that @daniel-Azuelos is correct, and you need to specify your `ProgramArguments` like this (I've added `usr/bin/ssh` as mentioned above):

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/bin/ssh</string>
    <string>-F</string>
    <string>/Users/userx/.ssh/config</string>
    <string>dname</string>
    <string>/usr/sbin/imapd</string>
</array>
```

My reasoning for this is, the few `plist`s I can find on my system that use (more than one) `ProgramArguments` use this idiom:

```
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.divx.uninstall.preferences</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/bin/bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>if [[ ! -e "/Applications/DivX/DivX Preferences.app" ]] ; then open "/Library/Application Support/DivX/Uninstall DivX for Mac.app"; fi</string>
</array>
```

Note how `bash`'s `-c` option and the corresponding `command_string` are in separate arguments.